# Where does CLR store methods for instances of one type

Tags: c#, .net, clr

```
class MyClass
{
     public string MyProperty { get; set; }

     public void MyMethod()
     {
          //Do something difficult here
          //100500 lines of code here ...
     }
}
```

We have a lot of instances of `MyClass`.

Does CLR creates this really memory-expensive `MyMethod()` *for any instance of the class*?

Comment: 100500 lines of code inside of one method !?

Comment: *100500 lines of code* I'd love to see that method please ?

Comment: That [god class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) is big enough to justify a brand new religion

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of [Where are methods stored in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298122/where-are-methods-stored-in-memory)

Comment: 100500 - Idiomatic usage meaning 'a very large number.'
The question was purely hypothetical.

Comment: Damn, closest I can get is 8800 lines of code in 1 method ;p https://gist.github.com/leppie/732ca72f4b2c6126acd2 (initialization code generated for IronScheme, loads very fast, < 100ms when NGEN'd)

Comment: '100500' is the same as 'over 9000', not an actual number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not. This method will compiled once, when we have the first call of this method. Then the compiled code will be used by any instance of type `MyClass`. So any performance hit happens only in the first call of this method, which from IL code will be compiled to native code.

Below, I posted two images that may make this more clear:

[image]

and

[image]

For further information, please take a look at this book [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean

> Does CLR creates this really memory-expensive MyMethod() for *every* instance of the class?

No, the **code** for the methods of classes is only produced for each method once.

However, the **data** associated with each new instance of a class will be allocated and stored on the managed heap (which defines the `this` location of the instance), and each method invoked on a class instance will [silently pass the `this`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-c/0596001177/ch04s02.html) reference (pointer) of the instance as a hidden argument to the method.

Take for instance this snippet:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var anotherFoo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
anotherFoo.Bar();
```

The dissassembly shows how the two `this` references get passed as parameters to the call to the same `Bar` method. (in fact, you can see the same Constructor call is also made for both objects).

```
            var foo = new Foo();
00000038  mov         ecx,592758h 
0000003d  call        FFC8F840
00000042  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax 
00000045  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000048  call        FFCA9F00 
0000004d  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch] 
00000050  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax ** [ebp-44h] = this for foo 
            var anotherFoo = new Foo();
00000053  mov         ecx,592758h 
00000058  call        FFC8F840
0000005d  mov         dword ptr [ebp-50h],eax 
00000060  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-50h] 
00000063  call        FFCA9F00 
00000068  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-50h] 
0000006b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax  ** [ebp-48h] = this for anotherFoo
            foo.Bar();
0000006e  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-44h] ** pass foo to `Bar()` across in ecx
00000071  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
00000073  call        FFCA9EF8   ** Bar()'s address
00000078  nop 
            anotherFoo.Bar();
00000079  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-48h] ** pass anotherFoo to `Bar()` in ecx
0000007c  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000007e  call        FFCA9EF8 ** You can see the same "Bar()" address is being called
00000083  nop
```